# Can't load mongodb fixtures with php7 and symfony 3

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to load fixtures for a mongodb database with symfony but I got an error. When I launch

> php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:fixtures:load

I got this error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
>     Attempted to load class "Manager" from namespace "MongoDB\Driver".
>     Did you forget a "use" statement for "League\Fractal\Manager"?

Here is my fixture

```
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\MongoDB;
class LoadTimeLineData implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
    }

    public function add(ObjectManager $manager, array $data)
    {
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I don't where the "Manager" come from.

If someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Please, add `use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;` under `namespace`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste the uses. They were already added.                    `use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;`                             `use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;`

Comment: Could you run the command with `--verbose` to see a more precise error ? (line and class).

Comment: I resolved the problem. I added the `php_mongodb.dll` only in the `php.ini` of apache. So mongodb worked only when i make requests through the urls, but not in the console. I had to add it to the `php.ini` of php too. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. I added the php_mongodb.dll only in the php.ini of apache. So mongodb worked only when i make requests through the urls, but not in the console. I had to add it to the php.ini of php too.
Thank you –